# Setup SSH key per user for Git access

Tags: ssh, git

I'm setting up a site that will have multiple development instances running on the same server. Essentially, we'd have dev-a.whatever.com, dev-b.whatever.com, etc.. all running off a single server.

I want to give each user some bit of SSH access in order to update and check in code from our Git repository and to manage files via SFTP. However, I want to restrict each user to their own site as well. So if you have access to dev-a.whatever.com, you don't also have access to dev-b.whatever.com and so on.
The restriction is already in place if I login via FTP as a certain user, I can't navigate outside my own site -- but if I grant SSH access to that account I can immediately navigate to any file on the server in SFTP.

Is RSSH part of the solution? And how can I assign the correct SSH pub key to the corresponding user? We're using BeanStalk for our Git repository management if that makes any impact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a [Unix permissions group](http://www.udel.edu/topics/os/unix/general/unixgroups.html) for each site, add users to the appropriate group, and then modify your file/dir permissions to only allow users in the proper group to be able to access files for that site.

Comment: Thank you! Permissions are fixed, now I just need to figure out the SSH key issues and I'll be set.

Comment: Actually, I think I have it all figured out. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it worked out.